# Number to Turkish text app

Tags: c#, .net, text, internationalization, translation

I m Trying to convert a number entered in the text box post.But I can not find the right reasons, does not work.Are you also please have a look.Thank you in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NumberToText
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void NumberControl()
        {
            if ((txtNumber.Text.Length>7))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a smaller number");
            }
        }
        public void ReadNumber()
        {


            try
            {
                int ones, tens, hundreds, thousands, tenthousands, hundredthousands, 

millions;
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text);

                int[] array=new int[7];



                for (int j = 0; j < txtNumber.Text.Length; )  
                {

                    array[j] = (number / (10 ^ (txtNumber.Text.Length - 

(txtNumber.Text.Length - j)))) % 10;
                    j += 1;
                }
                if (txtSayi.Text.Length != 7) 
                {
                    for (int i = 6; i >= txtNumber.Text.Length; )
                    {
                        dizi[i] = 0;
                        i-=1;
                    }
                }

                  ones = array[0];
                  tens = array[1];
                  hundreds = array[2];
                  thousands = array[3];
                  tenthousands = array[4];
                  hundredthousands = array[5];
                  millions = array[6];

                //Converting to numbers in TURKISH Text

                string[] a_ones = { "", "Bir", "İki", "Üç", "Dört", "Beş", "Altı", 

"Yedi", "Sekiz", "Dokuz" };
                string[] a_tens = { "", "On", "Yirmi", "Otuz", "Kırk", "Elli", 

"Altmış", "Yetmiş", "Seksen", "Doksan" };
                string[] a_hundreds = { "", "Yüz", "İkiyüz", "Üçyüz", "Dörtyüz", 

"Beşyüz", "Altıyüz", "Yediyüz", "Sekizyüz", "Dokuzyüz" };
                string[] a_thousands = { "", "Bin", "İkibin", "Üçbin", "Dörtbin", 

"Beşbin", "Altıbin", "Yedibin", "Sekizbin", "Dokuzbin" };
                string[] a_tenthousands = { "", "On", "Yirmi", "Otuz", "Kırk", 

"Elli", "Altmış", "Yetmiş", "Seksen", "Doksan" };
                string[] a_hundredthousands = { "", "Yüz", "İkiyüz", "Üçyüz", 

"Dörtyüz", "Beşyüz", "Altıyüz", "Yediyüz", "Sekizyüz", "Dokuzyüz" };
                string[] a_millions = { "", "Birmilyon", "İkimilyon", "Üçmilyon", 

"Dörtmilyon", "Beşmilyon", "Altımilyon", "Yedimilyon", "Sekizmilyon", "Dokuzmilyon" 

};

                lblText.Text = a_millions[millions] + " " + a_hundredthousands

[hundredthousands] + a_tenthousands[tenthousands] + " " + a_thousands[thousands] + "  

" + a_hundreds[hundreds] + " " + a_tens[tens] + " " + a_ones[ones];

            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }




        private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NumberControl();
            ReadNumber();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to reformat your code to make it a little bit more readable :)

Comment: @enzglk, when I entered the question it wasn't formatted and was everywhere..  It is better now.

Comment: @enzglk: I reformatted your code for you. In future, you should use a code block (select the code and press **Ctrl+K**).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the problem my number to text c# code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199492/what-is-the-problem-my-number-to-text-c-code)

Comment: Ok.So sorry.I m new in this site.Thanks a alot @Moo-and @Will

Comment: Oh good!  I'm glad to see you got the help you needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < txtNumber.Text.Length; )  
{
    array[j] = (number / (10 ^ (txtNumber.Text.Length - (txtNumber.Text.Length - j)))) % 10;
    j += 1;
}
```

`(txtNumber.Text.Length - (txtNumber.Text.Length - j))` is `j`, so:

```
for (int j = 0; j < txtNumber.Text.Length; j += 1)  
{
    array[j] = (number / (10 ^ j)) % 10;
}
```

You're XOR'ing 10 with j?

Also, "Sekizmilyon" is not a word. You need a put a space in between.

Comment: He probably wanted to write `Math.Pow`.

Comment: Probably. Though starting with the full number and shifting it down at each step usually works better, you just need a full division at each step.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to calculate a power of 10 with `^` when you probably mean `Math.Pow`. Using the reduction **aib** suggested, your line:

```
array[j] = (number / (10 ^ (txtNumber.Text.Length - (txtNumber.Text.Length - j)))) % 10;
```

becomes:

```
array[j] = (number / (int)Math.Pow(10, j)) % 10;
```

A couple of other suggestions:

1. Change `NumberControl` to return a bool so you can skip the call to `ReadNumber` if the entered number is too large. Currently it goes into `ReadNumber` even if the number is more than 7 digits, which results in an array out of bounds error
2. The block of code starting with `if (txtSayi.Text.Length != 7)` seems redundant.